# How to render the sorted array of objects using UseMemo ReactHooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to render the sorted array of objects using ReactHooks i have used useMemo for the same and redux as well. Could someone suggest me the best practies for it. Any suggestions on what am i doing wrong here?

I have put the post.js below as well.

I'm trying to render the sorted array of objects using ReactHooks i have used useMemo for the same and redux as well. Could someone suggest me the best practies for it. Any suggestions on what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

HomePage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
    import Post from "../../Components/Post/Post";
    import "./HomePage.css";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const HomePage = () => {
      const [posts, setPosts] = useState("");
    
      let config = { Authorization: "................" };
      const url = ".........................";
    
      useEffect(() => {
        AllPosts();
      }, []);
    
      const AllPosts = () => {
        axios
          .get(`${url}`, { headers: config })
    
          .then((response) => {
            const allPosts = response.data.articles;
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
      };
    
      const newPostsByTitle = useMemo(() => {
        allPosts.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)), [posts];
      });
    
      return (
        <div className="home">
          <div className="select">
            <select
              name="slct"
              id="slct"
              onChange={(e) => newPostsByTitle(e.target.value)}
            ></select>
          </div>
          <Post className="Posts" posts={posts} key={posts.title} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default HomePage;

Post.js
import React from "react";
import "./Post.css";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const Post = (props) => {
  const displayPosts = (props) => {
    const { posts } = props;

    if (posts.length > 0) {
      return posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="Post" key={post.title}>
              <img
                src={post.urlToImage}
                alt="covid"
                width="100%"
                className="img"
              />
              <h5 className="title"> {post.title}</h5>
              <p className="author"> {post.author}</p>
              <p className="description"> {post.description}</p>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        );
      });
    }
  };
  return <div className="Posts">{displayPosts(props)}</div>;
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: Seems like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TJ Kind of, but firstly this code needs to work

Comment: Ah I thought it already works

Answer (score 0):

You have a incorrect understanding of what the axios call dos I think.
This is just a function that on trigger will download the data, but you need to store it somewhere (e.g. posts) and use these posts instead of the api call:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); // Use an empty array as defualt so it does work without data before the call
...
  const AllPosts = () => {
        axios
          .get(`${url}`, { headers: config })
    
          .then((response) => {
            const allPosts = response.data.articles;
           setPosts(allPosts) ?? You need to save the posts somewhere, since allPosts is not accessible outside of this function. Sicne you already have a useState, save them there
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
      };
    
const newPostsByTitle = useMemo(() => {
    return posts.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)), [posts]; // Using {} requeores the return keyword, if you omit the {} you dont need the return statement
}); // Now access the posts saved in state to sort them
```

Also the key in `<Post className="Posts" posts={posts} key={posts.title} />` does not work, since posts is an array not an object. So remove it.

Comment: Im trying render through by select sort. is the JSX correct what i have coded?

Comment: No this is also not correct, What do you want to acheive excatly with it? What should this do:  onChange={(e) => newPostsByTitle(e.target.value)}

Comment: As the posts are rendered users can use the select dropdown  option to view the posts by sorting example title, author etc. I have posted the post.js below HomePage.js

Comment: Please read on what useMemo does, it does not track the select, but instead pdtes itself when posts change, So you need to track the selected option and sort within the useMemo if dependence of the sorting key.